# QuickFIX remove tag from logon process

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm using QuickFIX and Python to initiate a connection to a fixserver process which handles FIX5.0SP2. When I'm trying to initiate a connection I receive a disconnect after getting the following message: `(Message 1 Rejected: Required tag missing:1137)`. 
This tag is not mandatory by my fixserver process and I'm trying to remove it from the logon process. I removed it from the FIXT11.xml and created a custom xml for this but without any success. Do I miss something? I thought you can easily switch them from mandatory to non-mandatory in this file?

Here is my config:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
UseDataDictionary=N
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
AppDataDictionary=/home/foo/Documents/QuickFix/fix_specs/FIX50SP2CustomTags.xml
TransportDataDictionary=/home/foo/Documents/QuickFix/fix_specs/FIXT11CustomTags.xml

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
ConnectionType=initiator
SenderCompID=FIXSRV
TargetCompID=RTD
ReconnectInterval=30
HeartBtInt=30
StartTime=00:30:00
EndTime=23:30:00
SocketConnectProtocol=TCP
SocketConnectPort=1284
SocketConnectHost=X.X.X.X
FileStorePath=/home/foo/Documents/QuickFix/data
FileLogPath=/home/foo/Documents/QuickFix/logs
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N
#ValidateUserDefinedFields=N`
```

Here is the quickfix output with fix message:

```
<20170213-12:52:41.812, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, event>
  (Created session)
<20170213-12:52:41.813, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, event>
  (Connecting to X.X.X.X on port 1284)
Sent the Admin following message: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=77|35=A|34=1|49=FIXSRV|52=20170213-12:52:41.816|56=RTD|98=0|108=30|141=Y|1137=9|10=140|
<20170213-12:52:41.817, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, outgoing>
  (8=FIXT.1.1|9=106|35=A|34=1|49=FIXSRV|52=20170213-12:52:41.816|56=RTD|50=FIX50|98=0|108=30|141=Y|553=FIX50|554=fix50|1137=9|10=083|)
<20170213-12:52:41.817, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, event>
  (Initiated logon request)
<20170213-12:52:41.820, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, incoming>
  (8=FIXT.1.1|9=000106|35=A|1128=7|49=RTD|56=FIXSRV|34=1|50=FIX50|52=20170213-12:52:41.639|98=0|108=30|141=Y|553=FIX50|554=fix50|10=228|)
<20170213-12:52:41.820, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, event>
  (Message 1 Rejected: Required tag missing:1137)
<20170213-12:52:41.820, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, event>
  (Tried to send a reject while not logged on)
<20170213-12:52:41.820, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, event>
  (Required field missing from logon)
<20170213-12:52:41.820, FIXT.1.1:FIXSRV->RTD, event>
  (Disconnecting)
```

Update:
I tried to change that field `<field name='DefaultApplVerID' required='Y'/>` to `required='N'` in my dictionary but without any effect. Other fields are possible to change them to non-mandatory and they are skipped when not set. Is this specific mandatory fix 5.0SP2 field hard coded and can't be non-mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

You've got

```
UseDataDictionary=N
```

and I'd guess that's the problem as long as the initiator / acceptor data dictionaries are in sync.

Comment: I changed it to UseDataDictionary=Y but still the problem is the same.

Comment: Have you checked that the required value for `DefaultApplVerID` is set to N in the Logon message in the data dictionary and not some other message?

Answer (score 0):

The DefaultApplVerID must be configured. Check the Doc:
[Configuring QuickFIX](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html)

> DefaultApplVerID:
>
> Required only for FIXT 1.1 (and newer). Ignored for earlier transport versions. Specifies the default application version ID for the session. This can either be the ApplVerID enum (see the ApplVerID field) or the BeginString for the default version.

If you remove line **DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2** of the [DEFAULT] configuration,quickfix will show you the following:

> **Configuration failed: ApplVerID is required for FIXT transport**

In any case, try to place it in [SESSION] and set it like this:

```
DefaultApplVerID=9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. The checking for the field `DefaultApplVerID(1137)` is hard-coded in QuickFix's engine as it is mandatory as described in @Christian Quisbert's captioned specification.

I don't have the Python version of QuickFix but only Java version. But I think the implementation should aligns each other without big difference.

If take a look of `Session.java` under project of `quickfixj-core` (I am referring to *quickfix-2.1.0* ) in Java version, there is a method named:

```
private void next(Message message, boolean isProcessingQueuedMessages) throws FieldNotFound, RejectLogon, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType, IOException, InvalidMessage { ... }
```

From *line 953*, there is a code section for handling replied **LOGON** message as shown below:

```
final String sessionBeginString = sessionID.getBeginString();
try {
    final String beginString = header.getString(BeginString.FIELD);
    if (!beginString.equals(sessionBeginString)) {
        throw new UnsupportedVersion("Message version '" + beginString
                + "' does not match the session version '" + sessionBeginString + "'");
    }

    if (MsgType.LOGON.equals(msgType)) {
        if (sessionID.isFIXT()) {
            targetDefaultApplVerID.set(new ApplVerID(message
                    .getString(DefaultApplVerID.FIELD)));
        }

...
```

Which means quickfixj engine is expecting the field `DefaultApplVerID(1137)` exists in the incoming LOGON response if the `BeginString(8)` equals to `FIXT.1.1` and you cannot skip this validation simply by configuration.